# How can I get Chrome's new tab shortcut to open tabs in background?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press the new tab shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> it opens in the foreground.

How can I change it to open in the background?
I'm using Chrome 10.0.648.204 portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to let it open in background